# Jumping between using statements and other code in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there a key combo in VS2008 that will allow me to quickly jump to my using statments and then jump back to where I was after entering the required using statement?

Comment: Which language are you using ? C# ?

Answer (score 0):

you can go back where you come from by cntl + -

for jumping to using statement you can use cntrl + f, "using" (enter) :P